# Display Background-Image in CSS Under A Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I put the file under the "Styles" directory of my VS project, where my default sitemaster's CSS is located upon creation.

```
    body{
    background-image: url('..\Styles\Header.jpg');
    }
```

How can I use this properly to display the image in the background using external CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your css

```
body{
     background-image: url('~/Styles/Header.jpg');
}
```

or

```
 body{
         background-image: url('../Styles/Header.jpg');
    }
```

if your image is stored in Style forlder you can retrive by this code

Comment: The first choice worked for me. For still some odd reason even with hard-tried research, not all of these codes work perfectly for everyone. I'm still not sure why. :(

Anyhow thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Try this it works for me

```
 background-image: url(..\Styles\Header.jpg);
```

don't use single quote inside brackets.

Comment: Amit, can you please explain why not use single "quotes"

Comment: @KheemaPandey I don't know but I face same problem and resolved after removing the single quote and one more important point it works on all  browsers.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>

<title> Your page Name </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourcssresourcefile">
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**CSS**

```
   body{
    background-image: url('http://static3.businessinsider.com/image/52a0bbfd6bb3f7961363819e/the-most-amazing-satellite-images-of-the-year.jpg');
    }
```

---

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8g8nh/1/)**

**[Result](http://jsfiddle.net/8g8nh/1/embedded/result/)**

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to do it;

when you are trying to access your resource (image) with `relative path`:

```
body{
         background-image: url('../Styles/Header.jpg');
    }
```

when you are trying to access you resource (image) with `absolute path` :

```
body{
     background-image: url('~/Styles/Header.jpg');
}
```